# Map pegged svn:external back to sha1 git

Tags: git, github, svn

Our source code is located on an svn server where we have various svn:externals pointing both to other svn repositories as well as other git repositories.

Now, one of the externals points to a specific revision from a git repository. The syntax that is being used is:

`https://github.com/<user>/<software>/branches/<branchname>@1452`

So we are pegged to revision 1452. How can I map this revision number back to the git repository? I.e. how can I see which changeset this corresponds to in the git repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. It turns out that I can checkout

```
https://github.com/<user>/<software>/branches/<branchname>
```

using a SVN client. With this checkout I can go into the log and find when the changeset 1452 occurred (i.e. the timestamp of the commit). Using the timestamp I can go back to the GIT checkout of the code and search for a changeset that happend at that exact timestamp and thus find out SHA-1 hash for the commit.

A bit cumbersome, but it seems to work.